# Proving that a polynomial is an even function given limited information

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $f(x)$ has degree $10$. We know also that $f(a)=f(-a)$ for $a\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Prove that $f(r)=f(-r)$ for all $r\in \mathbb R$ (i.e. that the polynomial is even)

Note: this is a radical edit which I hope captures the sense of the original question, which was rather unclear.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: do you mean the degree of the function is 10? So are we talking about a polynomial?

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus edit my question thank you, bad english sorry

Comment: Are you saying that $f(1)=f(-1), f(2)=f(-2), \dots f(5)=f(-5)$?

Comment: Perhaps you could show some effort toward solving this, and that would make the question clearer.

Comment: @MatthewConroy yes

Comment: In fact, i really dont know how to solve this, i tried to use interpolation, but this didnt help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 9$ (since even powers, including the term in $x^{10}$ cancel out during subtraction) and $g(\pm1)=g(\pm2)=g(\pm3)=g(\pm4)=g(\pm5)=0$. Therefore $g$ has $10$ distinct roots i.e. more than its degree, which implies $g \equiv 0 \iff f(x)=f(-x)$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Alternative proof, based on the same idea: $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\deg g\le \deg f = 10$. But $g(\pm1)=g(\pm2)=g(\pm3)=g(\pm4)=g(\pm5)=0$ and also  $g(0)=f(0)-f(0)=0$ so $g$ has $11$ distinct roots, which implies $g \equiv 0 \iff f(x)=f(-x)$

Answer (score 0):

If you plug one of the values in the polynomial, you get a linear relation between its $11$ coefficients. If you plug the opposite value to get the same linear relation, with alternating signs. Subtracting the two, every other term vanishes.

In the end, you get a non-singular system of five equations in five unknowns (the coefficients of the odd powers of $x$), which has a zero right-hand side. Hence all these coefficients are zero.